# Resetting fields in edit mode

Tags: custom-form, form, metadata, powerapps-forms, sharepoint-fields

Sharepoint customized form is resetting when opening item to edit My team needs to open items many times to check off completed tasks but when I open the form the fields reset what am I missing if my team can’t see item current data